# Calculating current using Lorentz Force

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

This problem comes from a chapter on Lorentz Force in my book on electromagnetism. Previous chapters were purely about electricity, this is the first one to include magnetism. So the assumption is I don't know any of Maxwell's equations yet (except ofcourse for Gauss's electric flux theorem). It consists of two parts, of which I have the answers but not the method. The second part has me completely stumped.

A thin metal ring turns around the axis through its center with a constant angular velocity $\omega$. The resistance in the ring is negligible. A static, homogeneous magnetic field $B$ is present through the ring parallel to the rotation axis.

**Question 1:** On the ring is a single spoke with length $l$ and resistance $R$. Calculate the electric potential induced on the spoke. (Answer: $\Delta V = \frac{\omega B l^2}{2})$

**Question 2:** Imagine the induced potential is tapped by placing two contacts, one in the center of the weel, and one at the top of the wheel. The resistance on the wire connecting these contacts equals $0.5R$. Calculate the current running through this wire. (Answer: $I = \frac{\omega B l^2 n}{(n+2)R}$)

[image: Ring in magnetic field]

First off, the Lorentz force on every part of the ring and the spoke would be pointing towards the center. Finding the potential is a matter of integrating the electric field along the spoke, which can be found using the Lorentz force equation: $E = \frac{F_{L}}{q} = v B sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \omega B l$. I understand the math for the first question, but what has actually happened inside the spoke? Did a negative charge gather at the center of the ring? Or is the Lorentz force just the thing that keeps the ring's rotational motion going?

The second question, and more specifically its answer, has me completely stumped. I'm not even sure if I know what the $n$ represents that suddenly pops up in the answer. The only $n$ I've run into before was used to define the amount of point charges in a system. I find I'm having a hard time intuitively describing what is going on too. The current flows out of the spoke, into the external resistance, and then what? Does it make a loop around the ring until it reaches the spoke again? Does it split both ways of the ring ending up back in the spoke? Is this current constant over time? Also, since the question specifically uses the phrase 'the potential is tapped', does this mean the potential in the spoke starts dropping once the current starts flowing?

Comment: For the first question, the rotational motion is due to some external force, e.g. an axel. The Lorentz force produces a radial force on the charges (electrons) in the spoke, creating a current along the length of the spoke. The second question's answer indeed seems a little mysterious with the $n$. Based on its form, it appears the equivalent resistance of the circuit is $R_{eq} = R/2 + R/n$. The $R/2$ is from the attached wire, while the $R/n$ represents $n$ parallel paths each with resistance $R$. This means $n$ could refer to the number of spokes. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: For the 1rst question only :
\begin{equation}
\Delta V=\int\limits_{center}^{end}\left( \mathbf{w} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{B}\right)\boldsymbol{\cdot} d\mathbf{r}=\int\limits_{0}^{\ell}\omega r Bdr= \dfrac{\omega B \ell^2}{2}
\tag{01} 
\end{equation}
For the 2nd question : Your book on electromagnetism ??? (Title, Author)

Comment: While dealing with the first question, the external wire isn't actually attached. So when you say 'the Lorentz force creates a current along the length of the spoke', the charges don't actually have anywhere to go. Am I right then in saying a certain amount of charge gathers at the end of the spoke in the center of the wheel?

Comment: On the 2nd question, there definitely is only one spoke on the wheel. Disregarding the given answer for a moment, do you mean to say calculating the current would be as simple as using Kirchhoff's laws for resistances in series? Somehow I doubt that, for the reason that this question was specifically designed to test knowledge of that particular chapter on magnetism. The second question would have nothing in particular to contribute to that, as Kirchhoff's laws have been handled in an earlier chapter...

Comment: Though your reasoning for $n$ spokes does make sense. I'm not ruling out an error in the exercise text, it's not directly from the book, it's from a set of extra exercises made alongside the book. But are you sure the magnetic field or the moving conductor wouldn't affect the usability of Kirchhoff's laws at all?

Comment: Zeno, Welcome to SE. I saw accidentally your 3 comments. The site informs a user that  you post a comment  for him if you begin it  with @HisName. If you wonder why the site informs you about our comments we post without your name , the reason is that these comments are below your question and concerns you, so this is not necessary.

Comment: @Frobenius Thank you, yes I realized I forgot to mention the username but apparently after five minutes you can no longer edit your comments.

Comment: If I can't edit a comment or can't make extented changes in five minutes, I usually do this : [step 1] I copy-paste the comment in a text editor (Notepad for example). Note that you can copy-paste also the MathJax code for equations or inline expressions. [step 2]  I make any changes, I correct errors etc. [step 3] I post the new comment. [step 4] I delete the old comment.  If your old comment is short delete it and post a new.